# How to download branches from git repo when it is deleted from local but exist in repo as a user branch

Tags: git

I got a scenario like below,

```
Cloned the remote repo for the git url. Then the default remote branch showing local is say "D"
1 Created a new branch X
2 checkout X
3 did all the changes
4 added the files
5 Committed the files
6 and Did a rebase and pushed my branch to remote
7 And created a pull request
```

Everything was going good, but last day I had to update my system and unfortunately I had to reinstall OS & all the apps...

Is there a way I can download the branch X and keep working on it if pull request is rejected or not.( just like nothing has happened)
 Branch X is just my branch, no one else should see it inside the git login

Comment: Just clone the remote again? Assuming that you did in fact push branch X to it, it should still be there.

Comment: thanks, I cloned the remote and now I see the branch D back, but not showing X. Do you mean loginto my git , goto my branch in git branch, then clone using the CloneURL with my-personal branch clone-url ? So in short I will do 2 coloning, 1 for the D, and one for X? please advice ...

Comment: you did not push your branch X, that's why the X branch is not showing.

Comment: Try `git branch -a`. This lists all the remote branches, check if the branch X exists here. It would be something like `remotes/origin/branch-X`.

Comment: @kashyapkn Great thanks  !! it showed my deleted brach like `*D` `remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/D` and in next line it showed my branch `remotes/origin/X` what will be next command to bring it to local and check out that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the list of all remotes branches use

```
git branch -a
```

To create a new branch in local using a remote branch

```
git checkout -b <local-branch-name> remotes/origin/<remote-branch-name>
```